# How to view Internet Explorer auto-detected proxy settings?

Tags: internet-explorer, proxy, auto-detect

When Internet Explorer is set to auto-detect proxy settings, is there a way to view what it detects?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The settings are retrieved from http://wpad/wpad.dat which is a javascript file describing which proxy server should be used in which situation. Your best bet is to open that URL and figure the proxy out from the contents it returns.

Comment: Ah, excellent. Here is more detail on the Web Proxy AutoDiscovery protocol: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol

Comment: Are you sure that's the link?  What's wpad's top level domain?

Comment: Oh... I see.  I should use wpad in my local domain

Comment: This doesn't work for all networks. Sometimes proxy is autodetected over dhcp (inform verb) rather than http wpad.

Comment: As mentioned [elsewhere](http://superuser.com/a/346376/35237), the actual proxy can be found in lines with `PROXY` - in my case I had to track back an array's generation function, though...

Answer (score 47):

If `http://wpad/wpad.dat` is not available, you can deduce which proxies are in use by browsing to a web site and then checking the TCP connection that was made.  It's not great, but it's at least minimally useful.

1. Inspect the output of `netstat -an | find "EST"` (short for '`ESTABLISHED`').
2. Go to a fresh site (one that you have not recently visited).
3. Run the `netstat` command again, looking for the new connection.  It might look like:

   `TCP    192.168.1.1:1989       192.168.1.88:8080       ESTABLISHED`

In this example, your proxy's IP is `192.168.1.88` and it is listening on port `8080`.

Note that this method only shows the proxy *currently* in use *for that connection*.  If more than one proxy is configured in your environment, and you want to know all of them, you may need to repeat the procedure above periodically to get the full list.

The same procedure can be used on non-Windows boxes (using `netstat -an | grep EST`, or whatever your OS uses to show active connections).

Comment: Nice workaround :)

Comment: Great indeed...

Comment: Updated for 2020, see newer answer below  [here](https://superuser.com/a/1569471/299967)

Answer (score 17):

I tried both solutions mentioned, and also [all sorts of others](https://superuser.com/questions/346372/how-do-i-know-what-proxy-server-im-using).

In the end what worked for me was [using Chrome to navigate to](https://superuser.com/questions/346372/how-do-i-know-what-proxy-server-im-using#1163035):

> chrome://net-internals/#proxy

which gave me the `.pac` file (= proxy auto-config file) which I could then download and read to determine the proxy that was being selected.

***=== Addenda ===***

As pointed out by @DaveInCaz and @ZachBloomquist, this [no longer works as of Chrome 71](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368515/how-to-see-the-proxy-settings-on-windows#30751938).

So what I did was:

1. Find the previous version of Chrome, which gives [70.0.3538](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history).
2. [Look this up](https://superuser.com/questions/936432/how-do-i-install-a-previous-version-of-chrome#987935) on https://omahaproxy.appspot.com, which gives version 587811.
3. Find that version of **Chromium** on the [snapshots page](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html).  The version seemed to be present on the [Windows 64 bit version page](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win_x64/), which leads me to the [587811 version page](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win_x64/587811/) with the file [`chrome-win32.zip`](https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Win_x64%2F587811%2Fchrome-win32.zip?generation=1535669834391189&alt=media).
4. Download, unzip, run `chrome.exe` and you can again use the address `chrome://net-internals/#proxy` to find the PAC script!

**So to summarize the steps required:**

1. Download Chromium version 70.0.3538 = build 587811 [here](https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Win_x64%2F587811%2Fchrome-win32.zip?generation=1535669834391189&alt=media) (Windows, otherwise see above steps).
2. Unzip and run `chrome.exe`
3. Navigate to `chrome://net-internals/#proxy`

Comment: Apparently this no longer works? Chrome does not display any useful information on that page. version 75

Comment: opens but does not display gui

Answer (score 1):

`netstat` technique in [earlier answer](https://superuser.com/a/508978/299967) is updated for Powershell Version 5.1.17763.1007 (Windows 10):

> `netstat -an | find --% "EST"`

The `--%`is new for Powershell 3.0 and newer, the "[verbatim arguments](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html)" parameter using the Stop Parsing symbol.  [Details on Find Error here.](https://superuser.com/questions/1208964/why-can-find-not-be-used-in-powershell)