# How to find out what proxy settings firefox is actually using when auto configured?

Tags: firefox, internet, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to view Internet Explorer auto-detected proxy settings?](https://superuser.com/questions/33588/how-to-view-internet-explorer-auto-detected-proxy-settings)

My workplace LAN now needs me to configure Firefox with
  "Auto detect proxy settings for this network"
to get to the net (similar setting in IE obviously).

However, having done that (and yes, it is now necessary to access anywhere offsite), I'd love to know what the IP address of the proxy machine is, what port it's on etc.  But I can't find a way to get Firefox to tell me that information (noting under `about:config`, couldn't find any extensions which seemed like they were likely to tell me).

Any tools out there (firefox or IE builtins, or separate utilities) which will satisfy my insatiable curiosity about what the proxy configuration actually is ?

Comment: Doh!  10s later I find this http://superuser.com/questions/33588/how-to-view-internet-explorer-auto-detected-proxy-settings .  Sorry, close as dup please!