# Setting proxy via cmd on Windows not working on browsers

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, proxy

**Environment**: Dell Vostro with Windows 10 10.0.16299

I created two scripts, which toggle between using or not using a specific proxy. The "add" one, sets the value 1 on the ProxyEnable registry key and also sets my proxy address

**proxyadd.bat**

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /f /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1

REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /f /v ProxyServer /t REG_SZ /d proxy:8080

set HTTP_PROXY=proxy:8080
```

The problem is that my browsers doesn't accept those settings unless i manually open the Lan Settings window (a.k.a. inetcpl.cpl). I only open it and do nothing (the settings were set correctly before, by the batch script), and then instantly the proxy works.

I've also checked if the window opening changes anything on the registry, but it doesn't.

Comment: This is a known issue with no known workaround.

Comment: oh great, cool! ¬¬

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who falls in the same problem, please check [this answer from Daniel B](https://superuser.com/questions/710921/windows-7-disable-proxy-via-cmd-and-put-in-effect?rq=1). It, along with my .bat, solved my problem.