# Unable to change/turn off proxy settings in Windows 8.1

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, proxy, virus

I am running windows 8.1 and my "Network Proxy Settings" don't seem to be under my control.

1. "Use a Proxy Server" slider is turned on.
2. "Address" is set to "http=127.0.0.1:8080;https=127.0.0.1:8080".
3. "Port" field is empty.

Below is a screenshot :

[image: My Proxy Settings]

The problem here is that whenever I try to turn off the proxy settings or try to change any of the underlying fields, it just switches back to the aforementioned settings automatically. I don't understand what's causing this and how to get rid of it. When I try to access proxy settings from my browser, they are greyed out with the message : **"Some settings are managed by your system administrator."**

Comment: Do you have UAC enabled?

Comment: Also is your account an administrator .

Comment: Check if you are an administrator if not login to the administrator account and enable UAC user access control under Control Panel\User Accounts\User Accounts

Comment: I am indeed an administrator and my User Account Control Settings are set at the topmost bar i.e closest to "Always Notify" if that's what you mean by enabled

Answer (score 0):

go to internet options under control panel then under connections-> lan settings set it to autodetect see the snapshot [image]

Comment: As I have mentioned in my question details, lan settings option is greyed out

Comment: Is it possible to login with another administrator account and try to change the settings?

Comment: i just found this workaround in super user can you give it a go with an administrator command https://superuser.com/questions/419696/in-windows-7-how-to-change-proxy-settings-from-command-line