# How do I install a previous version of Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I have a problem with the latest version of Chrome (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225926/how-do-i-download-a-file-with-webdriver-in-the-latest-chrome-version-43-0-2357-1) so I need to download and install the previous version of Chrome. A few places suggest FileHippo or OldVersion, but FileHippo only redirects to Google's Chrome download page and OldVersion only goes up to version 23.

http://filehippo.com/download_google_chrome/history/2/

http://www.oldversion.com/windows/google-chrome/

All the similar questions are out of date.

I already turned off auto update by setting the registry key.

Comment: You can try downloading an older version of Chromium, which is the source of Google Chrome. The downloads are buried within this repository:
http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html?path=Win/

Comment: The higher the folder number, the newer the version is. Each folder contains the zip file with the date it was released, so look for the release date that best suits your needs.

Comment: @Chloe - Try the next build below yours which would be the previous build.

Comment: @Ramhound But how do you know what the previously release build # was? It's not like there is a ledger which shows the date & version number for previous releases. If I currently have the latest version, there could be 1000 builds between the latest version and the last released version.

Comment: `chrome://version/` will tell you which version you have.  You then determine the when the previous version was released.  You then have a general estimate of which build you have to use.

Comment: @Ramhound That still would not help. Knowing my current version, which auto-updated, isn't the problem. You say "you then determine when the previous version was released", but don't specify how. Let's use an example. Let's say my current version is `43.0.2357.130`. So tell me, which build # corresponds to the previously released version? What _is_ the previously released version anyways, since they skip sometimes? What date was it released? The feature you seek to revert may have been the first code change after the last release.

Comment: You can also use chocolatey for this as they keep old versions of packages. E.g. choco install googlechrome --version 69.0.3497.10000

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can look up the build version of a Chromium version on https://omahaproxy.appspot.com.
Simply paste the version (e.g. 40.0.2172.0) into the position lookup field and submit.

In the output the "base position" represents the build number.

[image: example]

With this number you can finally find the corresponding download on either:

1. [this page](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html) - for builds before early 2016, or
2. [this page](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html) - for builds since early 2016

Updated links may be found on the [Getting Involved](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium) page of the Chromium Wiki.

---

Comment: Download version 46: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html?prefix=Win/339982/

Comment: @Ouroborus I'm getting _The requested version information could not be found at this time. An exception has been logged for the maintainer._ Every time I click on Lookup.

Comment: @GOTO0 I suspect you're constrained to versions that are actually in the index. 46.0.2490.86 works.

Comment: 49.0.2623.112 gives branch base position (there's no "Base position" anymore) of 663, I can't find that anywhere in the table.

Comment: I'm also trying to find the installation for 49.0.2623.112 as @Ray were. And I couldn't use the branch base position to locate the build.

Comment: @RayKoopa On chromium.org site it's written : "Sometimes you may have to decrement the commit number until you find one"
https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium#TOC-Downloading-old-builds-of-Chrome-Chromium

Comment: If you don't know a specific version number you can use: http://filehippo.com/download_google_chrome/history

Comment: Seems that newish Chromium versions are now in a folder named [snapshots](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html) rather than [continuous](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html). Found via [this helpful page](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium).

Comment: I just tried this out, and it appears to download the "Chromium" browser rather than "Google Chrome". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I installed 28.x and I just get a blue canvas.  Even the debugging tools, just blue.  Ideas, anyone?  I've tried compatibility modes.

Comment: The page is deprecated, the new one is https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/releases

Answer (score 16):

I've found [this page](http://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php)  in case anyone is looking for old versions of Chrome. It only goes back to as early as Chrome 48. But they do provide full binary package for the Windows version in the form of a self-extracting zip archive.

Comment: I don't really trust running any executable from a unknown 3rd party source.

Comment: You can verify the digital signature of the executable files. They are the original executable file issued by Google. All they do is just to generate a zip archive out of it. Nothing has been modified.

Comment: @steveJohnson But where can I find the checksums for Chrome?

Comment: @JRR, not sure about checksums, but I right-clicked chrome.exe and confirmed that the digital signature was for Google.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. I just had to extract the archive over the top of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application` and wipe my user data in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome`.

Comment: worked for me, after extracting create shortcut like "C:\Chrome\18.0.1024.45\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="..\User Data\18" --chrome-version=18.0.1025.45

Answer (score 7):

Google Chrome always keeps backup of previous version you can find you previous version in chrome installation directory

[image]

Comment: Its not helping, please share the 46 download link. 47 is by default getting installed in  a brand new pc.

Comment: I tried to use your example but it failed for me to go back to 46, and then when i installing google chrome i have no way to go back 46 , its always and forever going only to 47

Comment: Why do you want to go back to 46?

Comment: Go back to version 46. Because HTTP do not allow HTTPS for WebRTC. MP4 does not play in Chromium 46, Address bar not hideable. Please share exactly Google Chrome 46 download link.

Comment: Does mac version keep a backup copy of a previous installation?

Answer (score 6):

You can get an older version of [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/) from [Google's continuous integration servers](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html) at http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html.

Chromium is using the same code-base as Google Chrome but does not include certain things like the built-in Flash plugin and support for some audio/video codecs (e.g. MP3).

***NOTE***: Google has switched to another build integration server, therefore the given build server only hosts binaries built until 2014.

For newer versions you can follow the same approach as shown in this script: https://github.com/scheib/chromium-latest-linux/blob/master/update.sh

Also have a look at https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium

Answer (score 2):

You can find old versions of Chrome for:

- Mac: http://google-chrome.en.uptodown.com/mac/old
- Ubuntu: http://google-chrome.en.uptodown.com/ubuntu/old
- Windows (up to 48): http://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php

Some versions are available at: http://www.oldversion.com/windows/google-chrome/

This link give all [older versions of Chrome](http://filehippo.com/fr/download_google_chrome/history/) but unfortunately it redirects to the latest version.

Comment: I would never recommend to download software from an unknown domain. But `UpToDown` claims ‘Uptodown has become an international reference within the field of legal software downloads.’ …

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I prefer to download portable versions when dealing with older versions of software. Luckily, Google Chrome is one of those. SourceForge seems to keep a long history of PortableApps, so I recommend them for getting old versions of Chrome:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Google%20Chrome%20Portable/

I need to do some testing between Chrome 60 and 59, so I am going to install Chrome 59 as a portable app now.

Comment: Those are online installers. And since google deleted the old files from their servers, the installer won't work.

Comment: What version did you try to download? How old is "old"?

Comment: The online installer tries to download the files from the google server for an older Chrome version. But those files no longer exist as google deleted them. So the online installer won't work as it will throw 404 errors.

Comment: If Google doesn't have the old version, then you'll have to try OldVersions or these old repo but you'd have to trust a third-party that the binaries are not compromised.