# Chrome 53 not showing alert popups

Tags: google-chrome

In Chrome 53 popup alerts aren't showing up.

I've tested with versions through 48 to 53 (gotten from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/936432/how-do-i-install-a-previous-version-of-chrome/1048508#1048508)) and concluded that it was Chrome 53 has this problem.

I've also tested with fresh profile.

Chrome 53 comes with Material Design UI which I thought was causing it but [disabling it](http://www.howtogeek.com/266280/how-to-turn-chromes-new-material-design-on-and-off) didn't help.

Here's a video. In the console tab I type a simple `alert('hi')` and hit enter and it doesn't shows up. It's there but not visible because it takes away the control and I can't type anymore in the console tab. I keep clicking around (not shown in the video) and finally I manage to tell the (invisible) popup to go away by hitting <kbd>Escape</kbd> at which point I can type again:

[image]

Anyone else experiencing this?

PS: Same with the Profile popup that comes from the button on the top right.

Comment: I tried [disabling the Material UI](http://www.howtogeek.com/266280/how-to-turn-chromes-new-material-design-on-and-off/) but it didn't help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I began seeing the same behavior a month or two ago, and finally found a fix for this today.  There seems to be some problem either with the video driver, or with Chrome's use of DirectX acceleration.

You can fix the problem by disabling "Use hardware acceleration when available" and restarting chrome.

I'm also going to try updating my video driver to see if that helps, but if not, the workaround above seems to work flawlessly for me.

Comment: Wow! Disabling "Use hardware acceleration when available" fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: thx, it is working

Comment: ATI, confirmed: downgraded driver and everything is ok now. Tnx!